# SQL WHERE Id IN fitting all records

Tags: sql, sql-server

One simple question, i couldn't find answers in WEB becouse it's rather unusuall , but: 
How can i build SQL `WHERE something IN (...)` command which returns me every record just like SQL `something LIKE '%'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

`WHERE something IN (something)`

This will return every record where `something is not null` (same behaviour as `something LIKE '%'`)

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE something like '%value1%'
OR something like '%value2%'
OR something like '%value3%'
etc
```

Comment: Yes it would be good if I had for example 5 values, what when i have 1000 ? ;)